# Area under a curve using calculus

Tags: calculus, area

Of a curve in the form $y=f (x)$,
$\Delta (A)= \frac{1}{2} \, (2y+\Delta (y)) \, \delta(x)$....area of a trapezium,
But as $\delta (x) \to 0$, $dA=y \, dx$ though according to  the previous statement its $dA=y \, dx + \frac{1}{2} \, dx \, dy$,
I would like to know why $y \, \delta (x)$ approaches to $y \, dx$ where as 
$ \frac{1}{2} \, \delta(x) \, \delta(y)$ disappears.

Answer (score 0):

The area of the trapeze $dA$ consists of the rectangle $ydx$ and the triangle $\frac{1}{2}dxdy$. As $\delta(x) \to 0$, the triangle disappears and you only have the rectangle.

Answer (score 0):

You agree that ${\rm d}x$ is small. In fact it is small enough to state $$1+{\rm d}x = 1$$

So now multiply both sides with ${\rm d}y$ to get $$ {\rm d}y + {\rm d}x{\rm d}y = {\rm d}y $$ which implies that $${\rm d}x{\rm d}y = 0$$

Comment: The fact that 1+dx=1 is understandable,but if we multiply it by y instead of dy to get y+y.dx=y,it still denotes that y.dx=0

Comment: It is not the same because in ${\rm d}y + {\rm d}x{\rm d}y = {\rm d}y$ all the terms are differentials. What I meant to say maybe is ${\rm d}x{\rm d}y = 0$ compared to the magnitude of ${\rm d}x$ or ${\rm d}y$